# Coldfusion on Linux - cannot change permissions on a file

Tags: coldfusion, cffile

I've been banging my head against the wall on this one. I have a system that allows a user to FTP a zip file to the server. Then in the admin they can tell the application where this file is so a set of actions can be performed on the file.

1. Move the file out of the web root
2. Unzip the file
3. List the contents and insert data into database

Problem is, the file uploaded does not always have the proper permissions. I've tried changing them with the following:

```
<cfscript>
    FileSetAccessMode(myFile, "777");
</cfscript>
```

And

```
<cffile action="rename" mode="777" source="#myFile#" destination="#myFile#">
```

And

```
    <cffile action="move" mode="777" source="#myFile#" destination="#myFile#">
```

> 

But nothing will change the permission of this zip file. Note that if I perform any of the above actions on an image (.jpg) it works fine. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FTP'd files are unlikely to be owned by the webserver process, unless you FTP in with the same credentials as the webserver's running under. Unless the webserver owns the files, it won't be able to change the permissions on them.

Comment: That's a bummer. That means cfdirectory doesn't even have the permissions to delete the file. :-/

Comment: I don't think so... on UNIX deleting a file is a function of the permissions of the directory (write, mode 2) rather than a function of the permissions of the file. To see this, as root touch a file in your home directory.. it'll be owned by root but you can delete the file.

Comment: Yah, as bpanulla says - you should be able to delete the file, as long as the web server has write permissions on the directory the file's in. But you won't be able to change permissions on the "foreign" file, unless the server's running as root (DO NOT RUN AS ROOT).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the clarification guys. Changing the permission of the directory that the file live in worked. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If the Web server/ColdFusion server can read the file, have it copy it to a staging area and then delete the original file. If CF has write (and possible execute) permission to the FOLDER it should be able to delete the original file regardless of who owns it, even if it's set to mode 000 (no access for anyone).

Having uploads be placed in a sandbox and then moved to where the server expects them is a good security practice in any event.